# Difference between select count(*) from and select count('quoted string')

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm curious about that, time ago a somebody told me that the performance of a `count('quoted strin')` is better than `count(*)`

I mean, use `select count('quoted string')` instead `select count(*),` and the reason was that `count(*)` goes through all the columns and degrades the performance, other people told me that there is no difference... but if it's true, does this means that `count('quoted string')` is the same than a count against one of the columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count('any quoted string') or any constant expression or literal is equivalent. The engine doesn't need to access any columns to count the rows. You con confirm with EXPLAIN PLAN.

It is preferable and correct for counting total rows (cardinality) than count(col) because the latter is affected by null values.

In practice, there is no difference anymore between count(1) and count( * ) (without quotes) because the optimizer on any database worth it's salt recognizes count(*) as a request for the number of rows, and will not access all columns as one might expect.

The difference is between count(1)/count( * )/count('*')  vs  count(col) where the latter, again, will look for the rows with non-null values for col.

This is specified by the ANSI SQL standard.

Personally, I think count(1) or count( * ) are acceptable, but count('*') is poor form, and potentially confusing, and/or born out of confusion in the first place. I've never actually seen it used, and if someone thinks it is a performance "trick", they are simply confused and unaware of the effect of constant expressions in general.

Comment: yeah I know, count('*') it was the example, but could be ('a') or whatever, I have changed the post to be more clear.

Comment: Gotcha. It would be the same for any constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual difference, because '*' is a static value like 1, 'aaaa', 'b' and so on.

However if you replace '*' with a column name, the count will only count none null values.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) val1, COUNT('AAAA') val2, COUNT(col) val3
FROM (values(1), (null), (3)) x(col)
```

Result:

```
val1  val2  val3
3     3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Execution Plan tell us it is the same. You can check this by your own in the future. Open Managment Studio: `New Query->Include Actual Execution Plan` -> profit !

Also you can activate it with Ctrl+M.